# Feature Selection -

Tags: r, correlation, categorical-data, feature-selection

This is my first time working on a dataset with this sort of complexity. https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques

I am thinking of trying to maybe use a logistic or linear regression model to try and predict the prices (i.e. SalePrice).

My issue I'm stuck with is how to approach the feature selection of the independent variables since there are 80 attributes.

Things I've tried:

A correlation matrix (using Pearson) with corrplot()/cor() in R after converting the categorical variables from characters to factor form:

```
as.numeric(factor(Train$Street))
```

but the issue is the output of the graph is way too big to view trying to bunch 80 variables in.

[image: Correlation Matrix]

My question is...

1. Is a correlation matrix the right method for selecting the mixture of categorical and numerical attributes?
2. Maybe it's not for me to post in this part of the website, but is there a way to filter the scores in R to finetune and choose ones that are strongly related (i.e. >0.5 or <-0.5)?

Answer (score 0):

Couple things:

1. If your outcome is sale price -- a continuous variable -- why are you entertaining Logistic regression as a means of estimation?
2. Correlation is a problem for inference, but I don't really see it as a problem for prediction.  If all you want is to predict stuff, correlation isn't a big deal.  Conversely, uncorrelated predictors may hide hidden relationships since correlation measures the strength of a *linear* relationship.  The Wikipedia article on [correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) shows several cases where data are uncorrelated and yet a pattern exists.

Here is a little example.  I generate 1000 training examples from

$$ y \sim \mathcal{N}(X\beta, \Sigma) $$

and test on 10,000 examples.  I do this in two cases: where the features are highly correlated (largest correlation is >0.8 in absolute value) and the other where they are uncorrelated.  Here is the histogram of the testing errors.  Can you tell me which plot -- red or blue -- comes from the correlated features?

[image]

3. Correlation matrix is not a great way to determine which features to select for prediction since features may be uncorrelated with the outcome individually but jointly could help with prediction.  Consider the XOR example.  You have 2 binomial signals (1s or 0s).  The outcome is 1 if only one of the signals is 1, else 0.  If you looked at either signal in isolation with the outcome, the two would appear to be uncorrelated.  But jointly, the outcome is determined.  In addition, looking at the correlation matrix gives the false impression that you can select individual categories from a categorical variable.  For example, BMW might be a good predictor of net income, but if the BMW variable comes from a variable for which type of car a person owns, you can't just select the BMW variable and disregard the others.
4. Consider using something like LASSO or Ridge regression if you have lots of variables.

code for the plot:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rethinking)

K = 3
beta = rnorm(K, 2, 4)

S = diag(K) - diag(K)
while( max(abs(S))<0.9){
  S = rlkjcorr(1, K)
}

correlated_rmse = replicate(1000,{
  

  
  
  X = MASS::mvrnorm(n = 1000, mu = rep(0,K), Sigma = S)
  y = 2.0 + rnorm(X%*%beta, 1)
  d = as_tibble(X)
  d$y = y
  
  model = lm(y~., data = d)
  
  Xtest = MASS::mvrnorm(n = 10000, mu = rep(0,K), Sigma = S)
  ytest = 2.0 + rnorm(Xtest%*%beta, 1)
  
  dtest = as_tibble(Xtest)
  predictions = predict(model, newdata = dtest)
  
  Metrics::rmse(ytest, predictions)
  
})


uncorrelated_rmse = replicate(1000,{
  
  S = diag(K) 
  
  X = MASS::mvrnorm(n = 1000, mu = rep(0,K), Sigma = S)
  y = 2.0 + rnorm(X%*%beta, 1)
  d = as_tibble(X)
  d$y = y
  
  model = lm(y~., data = d)
  
  Xtest = MASS::mvrnorm(n = 10000, mu = rep(0,K), Sigma = S)
  ytest = 2.0 + rnorm(Xtest%*%beta, 1)
  
  dtest = as_tibble(Xtest)
  predictions = predict(model, newdata = dtest)
  
  Metrics::rmse(ytest, predictions)
  
})


p1 = hist(uncorrelated_rmse, main = '')
p2 = hist(correlated_rmse, main = '')

plot(p1, col = rgb(0,0,1,0.25), main = '', xlab = '')
plot(p2, col = rgb(1,0,0,0.25), add = T, main = '', xlab = '')
```

Comment: I'm guessing in this case the correlated features account for the blue plot and thus aren't a good indicator of prediction? So for a regression analysis of 80 or so features/attributes, it is incorrect to be selective in choosing only a subset of features? I should just take all the information and use a lasso or ridge regression instead?

Comment: @HubAccess The two plots lay on top of one another so there is essentially little difference in the out of sample error.  The point of my comment is that correlation is of little importance in prediction.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So in terms of feature selection for a mix of categorical and numerical variables, I shouldn't even use correlation? What other methods would work well in this case? Random forest for selection?